# Is it possible to simplify $y=100x\cdot\log_{x+1} 2$ (Solved)

Tags: logarithms

Is there any way to simplify the following equation, or any way to reconfigure it in a way that is possible to graph?

$$y=100x\cdot \log_{x+1} 2$$

Comment: $(x+1)^y=2^{100x} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the basic relations for logarithms $$\log_a(b)=\frac{\log (b)}{\log (a)}$$the expression juste write $$y=100\,x \,\log_{x+1}(2)=\frac{100\, x \,\log (2)}{\log (x+1)}$$ The remaining of your question does not look clear (at least to me).

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I needed, thank you!